# Creating graph with leaf nodes colored differently

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have the following data set (sample):

```
child,parent
Z,B
T,B
B,A
C,T
X,B
K,A
```

and i want to create a graph that has the leaf nodes differently colored. However, im unable to achieve it with the following cypher query:

```
load csv with headers from "file:///test.csv" as test
merge(n:Node{id:test.child})
merge(m:Node{id:test.parent})
merge(m)-[:TO]-(n)
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the leaf nodes to have a different colour than the other nodes you can assign a different label to them and choose a different colour for that label.

First I would assign the `(child)-->(parent)` relationship in a specific order by adding a `>` to your load query.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test.csv" AS test
MERGE (n:Node {id:test.child} )
MERGE (m:Node {id:test.parent} )
MERGE (m)<-[:TO]-(n)
```

Then i would traverse the freshly loaded *tree* to find the leaf nodes and I would assign them a new label. Assuming *B* is the root ode of the loaded tree.

```
MATCH (leaf:Node)
WHERE NOT ((leaf)<--())
SET leaf:Leaf
```

Then in the browser UI I would select the `Leaf` label and pick a different colour for it. Then something like this should return

```
MATCH path=(n:Node {id: 'B'})-[:TO*]-(end:Node)
RETURN path
```

Comment: If all :Node nodes are part of a tree, then you can just find all :Nodes with no relationships to children (according to whichever direction is used for relationships to children) and set the label, no need to traverse the tree.

Comment: :) absolutely true - i will make that change - thanks!

Comment: Thanks, just a small addition: apart from setting the new label (SET leaf:Leaf), I had to also remove the old label (REMOVE leaf:Node). Else the leaf nodes contain both the labels